# how to check if "textfield1" < "textfield2"

Tags: android, textfield, toast

I would like to check if a filled in textfield is greater than an other filled in textfield.
So like:

```
if (textfield1.getText().toString().equals(""))
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "textfield one is empty, please fill in a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i would like something like this:

```
if (textfield1.getText().toString().less than textfield2.getText().toString())
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "textfield one is less than textfield two, this is not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i can't find how

Comment: textfield1.getText().toString().compareTo(textfield2.getText().toString()) < 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there are numbers in your TextViews? Make an `Integer` from the `String` and compare those numbers:

```
Integer input1 = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText().toString()); 
Integer input2 = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText().toString()); 

if (input1 < input2) { }
```

If it is input length you are talking about use `String.length()` like so:

```
if (textfield1.getText().toString().length() < textfield2.getText().toString().length()) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(textfield1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && textfield2.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
    try {
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText().toString().trim());
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText().toString().trim());
        if(i1 > i2) {
            // do needfull here
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e("tag", ex.getMessage());
        // user entered some character which is not number
    }
}
```